# jQuery UI Widget After Load Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a custom jQuery UI Widget.  The widget contains resources that take a bit longer to load, so I would like to fire an event after everything has finished rendering on the page.

I have tried the following two methods but neither have worked:

```
_initializeEvents: function() {
    this._on(this.element, {
        load: function() {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
_initializeEvents: function () {
    this.element.load(function() { 
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

What can I do to capture an event after the widget has loaded.  I'd rather not set a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

5 Years late, but I had a similar issue and did this to solve it.

```
// Get an instance of your widget
var WidgetInstance = $("#ID");

// Take a copy of the original method
var tmp = YourWidgetName.YourMethodName;

// Extend the method with some extra code
WidgetInstance.YourMethodName = function () {
    // This line will run your current method
    tmp.apply(this, arguments);  
    // This code will run after that has completed              
    console.log("Kaboom");
};
```